# from lab_utils_uni import soup_bowl

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, jupyter

Why is the soup_bowl not working like Coursera’s lab in my local Jupyter (1st picture)?
%matplotlib widget is working fine but soup_bowl is not giving the 3d as the 2nd picture.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `soup_bowl` is a function, so try doing:

```
soup_bowl()
```

instead. The brackets are required to call the function.